# Openmp tasks : execution order

Tags: c++, openmp

Since I am working a lot with Openmp, I had this question in mind. I read somewhere that when working with tasks, ***there is no specific way for the tasks to be executed***.
Like in this example

```
// Compile with: g++ -O3 test.cpp -fopenmp

#include <cstdio>

int main(){
  int a = -3;
  #pragma omp parallel num_threads(3)
  {
    #pragma omp task
    a = 3;

    #pragma omp task
    a++;
  }

  printf("%d\n", a);

  return 0;
}
```

Does this mean that any thread can execute the 1st ready task (could be one of the three a++ or the a=3)??

Comment: The whole point about running multiple independend threads, is to not care about their execution order, no?

Comment: I've converted your question to a MWE.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ actually yes, I was just a bit confused on how exactly this mini program would operate, as I wanted to clearly understand the results and see what task is executed first. And thus, confirm the idea that I had.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, any thread can execute the 1st ready task. If this is not Ok, you can add **task dependencies** using the `depend` clause. Note however that you can specify dependencies only in the same task region (ie. between sibling tasks of the same parent task but not with others). The task scheduling tends to change significantly between different runtime implementation (eg. GOMP of GCC versus IOMP of Clang/ICC).

Note that variables in task regions are implicitly copied (like using `firstprivate`) as opposed to `parallel` regions. However, this is not the case when they are shared in the parent parallel section like in your code as pointed out by @Laci in the comments (in this case, they are shared by the tasks).

Also please note that the `#pragma omp single` only applies to the next statement, that is, the following task directive and not the second one. This means the second task directive should generate 3 task (1 per thread).

Comment: Using pragma omp single on the 1st task only is intentional, I was testing to really understand that the 3 threads when they create the 4 tasks, they can be executed differently and there is not a special order in the execution of the tasks.

Comment: According to [Data-Sharing Attribute Rules in OpenMP specification](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpsu103.html) "In a task generating construct, if no default clause is present, a variable for which the data-sharing attribute is not determined by the rules above and that in the enclosing context is determined to be shared by all implicit tasks bound to the current team is shared. " so I think `a` will be shared and the race condition should be corrected. Check the result on [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/nYbEvrfzr)

Comment: @laci Oh I did not see this sentence. I find the "determined to be shared by all implicit tasks bound to the current team" confusing/convoluted, but I think you are right indeed. I am not very convinced by the result of one compiler and clang/ICC does not seems to work recently on GodBolt: it turns out I found several OpenMP bugs few years ago (1 in GCC and several in ICC including data-sharing ones causing crashes due to a bad data-sharing behaviour in non-trivial cases like this). I will edit the answer. Thank you.

Comment: To avoid misinterpretation of complex rules of the OpenMP specification and to make the code more readable I prefer to use `default(none)` clause and explicitly define the sharing attributes of the variable(s). @IsLearning I suggest you doing the same. It also helps to avoid data race as you have to consider each of your variable(s) one by one.

Comment: @IsLearning A useful presentation about [tasks and data scoping](https://hpc-wiki.info/mediawiki/hpc_images/8/8e/Hpc.nrw_06_Introduction-TaskingAndScoping.pdf):